# Mysql query where x like wildcard efficent to which amount of data?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-like

I'm wondering until what amount of data a like wildcard query is efficent?

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE provider LIKE %orange% ORDER by result_date DESC
```

Do you think that this query will be efficent even in a large database ?

thank you for a feedback.

Comment: This query will result in a table scan, if you remove your syntax error (I assume a typo of yours). Cause is LIKE '%orange%'. Because of this pattern MySQL can't use an index. Maybe you want to look into [FULLTEXT search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: So, in a word: 'no'. Specifically '%...' cannot use an index. It's like arranging words alphabetically and then not being told the first letter of the word for which you're searching!

Comment: thank you. i see that it is better to use full text search, I did not know about it yet. i think this will work fine for what im planning to do! @VMai